# ¿Porque Python no encuentra el archivo que quiero importar?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-views

Estoy creando mi primer proyecto en Django. Tengo que importar la funcion `saludo()` del archivo donde estan las vistas de la aplicación web. (`views.py`). Esta es la función `saludo()`, aquí no hay ningún error:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def saludo(request):    #primera vista
    return HttpResponse("Esta es mi primera vista en Django")
```

El problema llega a la hora de importarlo al archivo donde debo guardar la URL de esta vista:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Project1.views import saludo


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('saludo/', saludo),
]
```

Visual Studio Code me indica que el problema está en donde estoy importando `Project1.views`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\DjangoProjects\Project1\Project1\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from Project1.views import saludo
ImportError: cannot import name 'saludo' from 'Project1.views'
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradecería.

Comment: En el archivo `urls.py` intenta importar la función saludo asi: `from .views import saludo` y prueba a ver como te va

Comment: Gracias, pero no ha funcionado. Sigue ocurriendo lo mismo

Comment: Recuerda eliminar la línea `from Project1.views import saludo` y añade la que te dije. Si te sale error comparte el mensaje por favor